# Не отрабатывает request mapping на Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

При requeste на контроллер выдает 404 ошибку page not found. Использовался пример из http://docs.spring.io/ и другие примеры. Ошибка одна и та же.

Ниже приведены файлы: web.xml, *-servlet.xml, контроллер.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="false">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/golfing-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>golfing</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>golfing</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/golfing/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

gorfling.servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vlad.home.controllers.*" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

контроллер

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView render() {
        System.out.println("WAS CALLED CONTROLLER METHOD render()");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("test");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/*")
    public ModelAndView others() {
        System.out.println("WAS CALLED CONTROLLER METHOD others()");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("test");
        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

Ниже приведен вывод из консоли tomcata.

```
мар 15, 2016 5:57:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
мар 15, 2016 5:57:26 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
мар 15, 2016 5:57:26 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Mar 15 17:57:26 EET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
мар 15, 2016 5:57:26 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/golfing-servlet.xml]
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 328 ms
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'golfing': initialization started
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'golfing-servlet': startup date [Tue Mar 15 17:57:27 EET 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/golfing-servlet.xml]
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
мар 15, 2016 5:57:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'golfing': initialization completed in 76 ms
```

Целый день пытаюсь найти ошибку, буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Еще бы лог ошибки.

Comment: А где его посмотреть?. Ошибки никакой нет в браузере 404 page not found.

Comment: Там же где вы взяли вывод из консоли томката.

Comment: В консоли ошибок нет.

Browser error: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7kgTZ.png

Idea output console: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YF0Rt.png

Comment: Возможно, поможет "@ResponseBody" в контроллере.
Запрос с клиента посылаете просто из командной строки браузера?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте убрать `RequestMapping("/")` из контроллера. `@RequestMapping` на уровне контроллера нужен, для того, чтобы добвать как бы префикс ко всем другим `@RequestMapping` на уровне методов этого контроллера. Например, если у вас есть `@RequestMapping("/foo")` на уровне контроллера, и `@RequestMapping("/bar")` на уровне метода, тогда, URL путь к методу будет /foo/bar.

Если вообще не писать `@RequestMapping` на уровне контроллера, то URL путь к тому же методу будет /bar.

Если не получится, попруйте поменять `<url-pattern>/golfing/*</url-pattern>` на `<url-pattern>/golfing/</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 0):

Так же, я бы заменил

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.vlad.home.controllers.*" />
```

на

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.vlad.home.controllers" />
```